# La tubería "nieto" no acaba de leer

Tags: c

Estoy realizando un código donde hago dos tuberías. Primero hago que el abuelo escriba en FD y lea más tarde el FD2 (el cuál escribirá el padre). Luego lo que tengo que hacer es que el padre haga dos veces lo mismo (leer y escribir). Y por ultimo el nieto va a leer FD2 y escribir FD.

El problema es que el resultado que me sale es el siguiente:

```
El abuelo está escribiendo...
El padre lee: Soy el abuelo
El padre está escribiendo...
El nieto está escribiendo...
```

Y luego se queda ahí esperando el prompt. Necesito que lo que ocurra después de que el nieto este escribiendo es, que este mismo saque la lectura del `FD[0]` que fue escrita por el padre. Luego necesito que el padre vuelva a leer `FD[0]`, el cual escribe el nieto, y escriba de nuevo `FD2[1]`, el cual acabará leyendo el abuelo.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h>

void main() {
  int fd[2], fd2[2];
  int pid, pidNieto;
  char lectura[30], lectura2[30];

  if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
    //un error ha ocurrido
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if (pipe(fd2) == -1) {
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  pid = fork();
  switch (pid) {
    case -1: //esto es un error
      printf("No se ha podido crear el proceso\n");
      exit(-1); //para dar error al sistema
    case 0: //el PID del hijo, que se convierte en padre al tener otro hijo
      //creamos el proceso nieto
      pidNieto = fork();
      switch (pidNieto) {
        case -1: //esto es un error
          printf ("No se ha podido crear el proceso\n");
          exit (-1); //para dar error al sistema
        case 0: //hijo
          printf("El nieto está escribiendo...\n");
          write(fd2[1], "Soy el nieto", 15);
          close(fd2[1]);
          printf("El nieto lee: ");
          read(fd[0], lectura, 15);
          printf("%s\n", lectura);
          close(fd[0]);
          exit(0);

        default: //padre
          printf("El padre lee: ");
          read(fd[0], lectura, 15);
          printf("%s\n", lectura);
          //desaparece de la tubería

          printf("El padre está escribiendo...\n");
          write(fd2[1], "Soy el padre", 15);
          wait(NULL);

          printf("El padre vuelve a leer: ");
          read(fd[0], lectura, 15);
          printf("%s\n", lectura);

          printf("El padre está escribiendo por segunda vez...\n");
          write(fd2[1], "Soy el padre", 15);
          exit(0);
      }
      break;

    default: //el PPID del padre, que se convierte en abuelo
      printf("El abuelo está escribiendo...\n");
      write(fd[1], "Soy el abuelo", 15);
      close(fd[1]);
      wait(NULL); //esperamos que finalice el proceso padre
      printf("El abuelo lee: ");
      read(fd2[0], lectura2, 30);
      printf("%s\n", lectura2);
      close(fd2[0]);
      exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como está tu código, no responde a la descripción inicial del problema. Según tu descripción (aunque no está del todo claro lo que debe hacer el padre), el nieto debería escribir en `fd` y leer de `fd2`, pero hace justo lo contrario.

Tal como lo tienes ocurre lo siguiente:

- El abuelo crea el padre. Después escribe en `fd` y luego se bloquea hasta que el padre finalice, para después leer de `fd2`
- El padre crea al hijo-nieto, después intenta leer de `fd` (posiblemente encuentre el mensaje que dejó el abuelo, aunque puede que no, ya que es posible también que lo haya consumido el nieto, como veremos luego). Si lo lee con éxito, emite un mensaje a `fd2` e intenta leer de nuevo de `fd` (donde ya no hay más texto, por lo que queda bloqueado, bloqueando a su vez al abuelo que está esperando a que el padre finalice)
- El hijo-nieto escribe en `fd2` e intenta leer de `fd`. Ya que el padre también estaba intentando leer de `fd` tenemos aquí una condición de carrera entre padre e hijo. Si el padre llegó antes y consumió el mensaje del abuelo, el hijo quedará bloqueado aquí y no despertará ya que nadie más escribe nunca en `fd`. Si es el hijo el que llega antes, podrá proseguir su ejecución (pero entonces es el padre el que queda bloqueado y por tanto el abuelo).

Todo este lío se resuelve si en el código del hijo-nieto cambias `fd` por `fd2` y viceversa, lo que además hará que encaje con el enunciado inicial.

Haciendo este cambio, el programa muestra lo siguiente al ser ejecutado:

```
El abuelo está escribiendo...
El padre lee: Soy el abuelo
El padre está escribiendo...
El nieto está escribiendo...
El nieto lee: Soy el padre
El padre vuelve a leer: Soy el nieto
El padre está escribiendo por segunda vez...
El abuelo lee: Soy el padre
```

Y finaliza normalmente. Aunque si te soy franco, esto es un laberinto tal que no estoy seguro de si esta es la salida esperada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Es lo que tu acabas de comentar. El problema es un poco lioso y yo creo que no me explique con la suficiente calridad. Muchas gracias de nuevo. Llevaba dos dias mirando el codigo y no encontraba el error, ha sido lo que tu comentabas, cambiar las tuberias de orden. Muy amable